# WiMax or alternatives

Tags: wireless-networking

I my spare time I'm a member of an international search and rescue team and one of the problems we have is communications. We can get international communications going using satellite phones and although they are expensive and sometimes slow, the systems are fairly robust. We'd like to find a system that will improve netwroked communciation over a few miles radius whilst we are in country so we can easily transfer information like maps, reports, photos etc. Is WiMax or something similar an option for us given we need something relatively simple and relatively small and lightweight to travel with or is there any other system that might be able to help?

Answer (score 1):

My ISP uses WIFI / WIMAX.  They use Tranzeo products.

My Route to the internet

Hop

```
1 - 10 miles to the AP (sector antenna)
2 - 10 miles via Point-to-point WIFI
3 - 13 miles via Point-to-point WIFI
4 - 1/2 mile Point-to-point WIFI
5 - router connected to CenturyLink
```

Comment: I'm curious: What speed do you get out of that?

Comment: Currently I am getting 2Mbps down and .5MBps up.  They are working on making the backbone links full-duplex, so it might (should) get better.  Where I live the other choices are Dial Up and Satellite.